# Custom XamGrid Columns Databinding Images/Buttons/Tooltips

Tags: c#, silverlight, data-binding, datagrid, infragistics

HI I am trying to utilize Infragistics controls in my app, particularly XamGrid.  I select a bunch of parameters the the grid brings back the results. I use to have this fully functional in the regular Silverlight DataGrid.  However I want to take advantage of the XamGrid's groupby column functionality.  While converting from DataGrid to XamGrid I had to make some changes to bindings and all that but I got it to compile.

However, halfway through loading, an error pops up with a XamlParseException
'Add value to collection of type 'Infragistics.Controls.Grids.ColumnBaseCollection' threw an exception. [Line: 238 Position: 40]' on my codebehind InitializeComponent();

Line 238 on the Xaml points right to my xamgrid as follows

```
<ig:XamGrid Name="gridResults" AutoGenerateColumns="False" VerticalAlignment="Top" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" Height="Auto" Margin="0" Width="765" IsAlternateRowsEnabled="false"  >
            <ig:XamGrid.SelectionSettings>
                <ig:SelectionSettings CellClickAction="SelectRow" CellSelection="None" />
            </ig:XamGrid.SelectionSettings>
            <ig:XamGrid.Columns>
                <ig:TextColumn x:Name="pieceTypeColumn" Key="PieceType" HeaderText="Type" Width="SizeToHeader"  />
                <ig:TextColumn x:Name="pieceNumberColumn" Key="PieceNumber" HeaderText="Piece Num" Width="SizeToHeader"  />
                <ig:TextColumn x:Name="jobNumberColumn" Key="JobNumber" HeaderText="Job Num" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                <ig:TextColumn x:Name="businessNameColumn" Key="BusinessName" HeaderText="Business Name" Width="256" />
                <ig:TextColumn x:Name="marketColumn" Key="Market" HeaderText="Market" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                <ig:TextColumn x:Name="openDateColumn" Key="OpenDate" FormatString="\{0:d\}" Width="SizeToHeader" />
                <ig:TemplateColumn x:Name="imageColPdf" HeaderText="PDF" Width="SizeToHeader"  >
                    <ig:TemplateColumn.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <HyperlinkButton HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="imageHLpdf" Click="HyperlinkButtonPDF_Click" Visibility="{Binding PDF, Converter={StaticResource marketConverter}}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=PDF}">
                                <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                    <ToolTip>
                                        <ToolTip.Content>
                                            <Image Source="{Binding Path=ttImagePathPDF}" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
                                        </ToolTip.Content>
                                    </ToolTip>
                                </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                <Image Source="/PrintOnDemand;component/Images/16x16/page_white_acrobat.png" Stretch="None"   HorizontalAlignment="Center" ></Image>
                            </HyperlinkButton>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ig:TemplateColumn.ItemTemplate>
                </ig:TemplateColumn><---------ERROR: Line 238----------->
            </ig:XamGrid.Columns>
       </ig:XamGrid>
```

As you can see, I need a hyperlink button in the column that displays an image icon, and has a databinded tooltip, which displays a thumbnail preview.

My question is if I converted everything over correctly and what options are there in XamGrid to get my desired effect of a hyperlink button that displays image tooltips.

Comment: What is the InnerException of the XamlParseException?

Comment: The Inner exception is null

Comment: Have you tried commenting the contents of the DataTemplate to see if making it simpler changes the behavior?